# How to print a string one char at a time with kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I wanted to display a string one character at a time in kivy. I tried doing this but it just displays the whole string(not one character at a time) when it's done.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from time import sleep

class someclass(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(someclass, self).__init__()
        l = Label(text= '',size_hint_y= 0, height='40dp', pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':0.5})
        self.add_widget(l)
        s = 'Hello hello hello hello'
        for c in s:
            sleep(0.5)
            l.text += c

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self): 
        return someclass()

TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blocking tasks are not suitable for a GUI, they have a [`life cycle`](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html#kivy-app-life-cycle) that allows them to update the components properly. The solution is to use [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock

class someclass(BoxLayout):
    s = 'Hello hello hello hello'
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(someclass, self).__init__()
        self.l = Label(text= '',size_hint_y= 0, height='40dp', pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':0.5})
        self.clock = Clock.schedule_interval(self.onTimeout, 0.5)
        self.add_widget(self.l)

    def onTimeout(self, dt):
        self.l.text = self.s[self.counter]
        self.counter += 1
        if self.counter == len(self.s):
            self.clock.cancel()

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self): 
        return someclass()

TestApp().run()
```